# Tree-shaking monaco-editor in an angular cli app

Tags: angular, webpack, monaco-editor, tree-shaking

I'm willing to use monaco-editor (vscode editor) in my angular app. I noticed in their documentation the recommended way to load efficiently this project with tree-shaking is to use a community webpack plugin: monaco-editor-webpack-plugin.

Unfortunately, this is not possible without ejecting angular webpack config which is not something I want to do.

I also noticed the amd version is 2MB which is enormous for a web app.

Is there a way with the angular cli to compile and bundle only the source code really used in monaco-editor (tree-shaking)?

I'm using angular 6.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution.  Having some problem with React app & webpack 4

Comment: Sort of yeah I switched to Ace editor which is only 400Ko. And I load it lazily with loadjs.

Comment: Sad, because it was a nice editor.  Will look at Ace again.

Comment: Same as you, but I don't think monaco-editor developers are interested by our use case. This is not the right tool if you want to integrate a code editor in a web app. VS Code for instance doesn't care about lazy loading specific features of the editor.

Comment: Nowadays, this tool could probably help: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack. Didn't tried it myself (yet) but in theory we could now tree-shaked monaco editor in an angular app using  @angular/cli.